# API errors on Facebook insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a lot of errors in my App when I go to developer block on Facebook Insights.
The problem is that I don't know which method is that produce the error.

The method is 'GET objectcomment'. Someone knows which API call is the equivalent to this method?